# Abort chain of activities for MassTransit Saga

Tags: masstransit, automatonymous

I'm trying to figure out how to abort a chain of activities, if one activity decides that there is something wrong, and the Saga should be Finalized.

For example:

```
Initially(
    When(UpdateRequested)
        .Activity(x => x.OfType<InitialSetup>())
        .Activity(x => x.OfType<StartUpdating>())
        .TransitionTo(Updating)
```

`InitialSetup` will configure the Saga based on some information loaded from the database. Let's that that it realizes that the data needed is missing, and the Saga should be finalized, before `StartUpdating` activity is run.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can throw an exception, catch it, and use the catch branch to finalize the saga.

```csharp
Initially(
    When(UpdateRequested)
        .Activity(x => x.OfType<InitialSetup>()) // activity throws
        .Activity(x => x.OfType<StartUpdating>())
        .TransitionTo(Updating)
        .Catch<MissingDataException>(x => x.Finalize())
);
```